# How to move ruby gems from one server to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a RoR server that I am decommissioning and need to move the existing Rails apps to a new server. The Rails apps are running Rails 2.3.5 and RubyGems 2.3.5.

The problem I am having is that some of the Gems do not seem to be available anymore - one example is thoughtbot-paperclip --version=2.3.1

I need to install these gems in order for the apps to work on the new server.

Would these gems have been removed from the remote repos? And if so how can I transfer them to the new server? I have tried just copying the entire gems folder from one server to the other but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the old gems got renamed, as they usually were in a `github_username-gem_name` format. But after GitHub stopped hosting gems and [gemcutter.org](http://gemcutter.org) came, they got renamed to only the `gem_name`, such as `thoughtbot-paperclip` to just `paperclip`.

You might get away with just specifying the version number in a Gemfile, such as

```
gem 'paperclip', '2.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gem has been renamed to simply `paperclip`.  [Check the repository](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).